# Passing props to component after declaration in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, role-based-access-control

I am trying to implement role based authentication as seen in this tutorial
[REACT AUTHENTICATION TUTORIAL](https://github.com/NemerSahli/React-Role-Based-Access-Control/tree/383baf6a3c39dcd232456e404f64972842ebb7ce)

This is my function for react-router-dom

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/addcloth" component={Authorization(AddCloth, [1], role, [storelist, sectionlist])} />
<Switch />
```

And this is my authorization function

```
    export default function Authorization(WrappedComponent, allowedRoles, userType, property) {
        return class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
            render() {
                if (allowedRoles.includes(userType)) {
                    let Component = <WrappedComponent />;
                    // some code to add property elements into Component
                    return Component;
                } else {
                    return (
                        <AccessDenied />
                    );
                }
            }
        };
    };
```

As storelist and sectionlist are 2 props for AddCloth component and I am trying  to pass that into AddCloth. In the tutorial he didnt mention about the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You need to send it as object.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/addcloth" component={Authorization(AddCloth, [1], 
    role, {storelist, sectionlist})} />
<Switch />
```

In HOC, destructure the props and assign to component.

```
    export default function Authorization(WrappedComponent, allowedRoles, userType, props) {
    return class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
        render() {
            if (allowedRoles.includes(userType)) {
                let Component = <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
                // some code to add property elements into Component
                return Component;
            } else {
                return (
                    <AccessDenied />
                );
            }
        }
    };
};
```